# How to get Response body (not response text) from webpage using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract response body of a webpage. The information I need is in the response body of page 43 out of 60. I tried using another solution which gives me some Chinese texts from the response body (I guess it is encrypted).

I tried some code which gives me response text which is not a requirement here. You can check the response body of page in developer tools-->network-->details-->response body.

It loads only when you click on network traffic capturing button and then refresh the page. It will track all the requests and responses.

**How do I get the Response body (not response text) from the webpage using VBA?**

Comment: You should include what you have done so far (the code).

Answer (score 1):

this is the code which gives me first response body but want to loop through all response bodies of a web page.

```
Sub HTMLsearch()
    Dim Html As String
    Html = GetHTML("https://portal.mylink.com/vspace/")

    ' Cyrillic characters are supported in Office, so they will appear correctly
    rsbody= Html
End Sub

Function GetHTML(Url As String) As String
    Dim request As Object
    Set request = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
    Dim converter As New ADODB.stream

    ' fetch page
    request.Open "GET", Url, False
    request.send

    ' write raw bytes to the stream
    converter.Open
    converter.Type = adTypeBinary
    converter.Write request.ResponseBody

    ' read text characters from the stream
    converter.Position = 0
    converter.Type = adTypeText
    converter.Charset = "Windows-1251"

    ' set return value, close the stream
    GetHTML = converter.ReadText
    converter.Close
End Function
```